# Excel cells suddenly not visilbe

Tags: excel

I do not know if this is the right place to ask but..

Since yesterday it is not possible to see the content of some cells.
In the cells is a formula, so I know there is something in the cells.

What I have done is:
Sheet1 has in cell G2 the autosom of column G `(=SUM(G:G)`
Sheet2 has in cell B5 the number of Sheet1 cell G2  `(G2(=Januari!$G$2)`
Sheet2 has in cell B18 the total of all months  `((=SUM(B6:B17)`

The content of cells B5 and B18 are not visible in the cell, but visible in the formulebar.

The things I have tried:
And failed:
Save the file
Close the file and reopen it.
Change the backgroundcolor
Change the textcolor

The only thing that works is showing the formula in the cell.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here and/or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are these the full formula? Or are they nested inside an `IF` type statement that yields blank given some condition. Have you tried force calculating the book? Dropping your computer from high platform?

Comment: Check for custom number formatting (ctrl+1) and conditional formatting for similar cell or font formatting.

Comment: Repeat the formula creation process on a fresh, newly created worksheet. That will tell you if the problem is with your formulas or with some issue on Sheet 2.

Comment: It is a full formula, not nested. There is no problem in a newly created sheet.

Comment: Create a new sheet and use `Format Painter` to try to force visible cells

Comment: Thank you all. I created a new workbook, and I have no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File/Options/Advanced and check the "Allow editing directly in cells" checkbox.